# Using Portal Keys from Capsule

Tags: ingress

When linking two portals will the link automatically check keys within Capsules or do you have to remove the key from the capsule to create the link?

I am sure I have linked a portal using a key in a Capsule but I haven't yet had the opportunity to repeat this test to confirm.

Anyone else able to confirm this?

Comment: You might have two keys. One is in capsule and the other not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> When an inventory item is inside a Capsule, it is in storage and
>   cannot be used. For example, XMPs inside a Capsule can’t be fired and
>   Keys can’t be used to recharge or link Portals.

https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/6011315?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

I'm equally sure you're mistaken.

Keys in capsules are not visible for linking.

Answer (score 2):

No, keys in capsules are not considered to be in your inventory for anything else than the item count.

This includes the check of an existing key for hacking. If you have a key of the portal in capsule, the portal will produce a new key with the hack, similar to what would happen if you dropped your existing key. Very, very handy for key farming!